# Is ctype_alpha() a better way to check if a string contains just letters

Tags: php, sql-injection

In the past, I have always used `preg_match()` to do this.

Just came across `ctype_alpha()` at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php.

Is this a quicker and/or less resource intensive way to confirm that a string just contains letters?

Note that I will be using this string later in a SQL query, and will be putting quotes around it but not doing anything more for SQL injection.  I know this is not typical, however, I am generating dynamic SQL, and wish to do it this way.

Comment: What's your definition of `just letters`?

Comment: @AmalMurali A-Za-z.  I guess others are okay too as long as there is no way there can be SQL injection.  The string will later be put in a WHERE clause such as `$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col='{$string}'`  Note that this query is a trivial example where I know better solutions are available.

Comment: This might help: http://codepad.org/ZIuMHd1Z

Comment: @AmalMurali.  Sounds like your opinion is "yes".  See any liabilities?

Answer (score -3):

ctype-alpha can have two positive and not only one. Check the notes on php manual about 'Tyrunur', and then think if the string is empty is true (second state).

So before go in your sql, you have:

- first to set and control each 'locale' for every net-user,
- then if empty or not and
- if is valid string or not.

After these you can use ctype-alpha. 
Are you sure is so fast? i don't believe so.